# In SQL Server, how can I concatenate multiple rows together into one by duplicating the column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data which looks something like this:

| FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- |
| John | Doe |
| Jane | Roe |
| Bob | Smith |
| Sue | Jones |

And I want to display all these people one after the other, like so, for a report where I'm reporting on some other table and want these people to be displayed inline:

| FirstName1 | LastName1 | FirstName2 | LastName2 | FirstName3 | LastName3 | FirstName4 | LastName4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | Jane | Roe | Bob | Smith | Sue | Jones |

I don't know exactly how many people there will be, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708261/sql-return-multiple-rows-as-a-single-row) won't work. How can I do this without knowing the number of people? I suppose it would be OK to leave out the numeric suffixes, even if that does make the data a bit less clear. Let's say the person names are coming from a Person table, even though the data I'm dealing with is more than just person names (I just simplified it to make it more understandable, minimal reproducible example and all).

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it using the link you tried together with dynamic sql. Not sure how usefull is an endless list of columns with FirstName and LastName

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, if i'm honest. You could use logic like I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns) but I would urge you to just reconsider what you want to do.